# Calling non template member function inside template member function

Tags: c++, templates, boost, shared-ptr

I am facing compilation problem while running the following program:
I am calling non template member function inside template member function but getting the weird compilation errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\shared_ptr.hpp>

class base
{
public:
    base()
    {

    }   
    void fun2(boost::shared_ptr<int> &data)
    {
        std::cout << "This is fun2" << std::endl;   
    }
    void fun3(boost::shared_ptr<double> &value)
    {
        std::cout << "This is fun3" << std::endl;
    }
    template <typename T>
    void fun1(int switchParam,T &resonse)
    {
        std::cout << "This is fun1." << std::endl;
        switch(switchParam)
        {
        case 0:
            fun2(resonse);
            break;
        case 1:
            fun3(resonse);
            break;
        }       
    }
};

void main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<int> myInt;
    int switchParam = 0;
    base b1;
    b1.fun1(switchParam,myInt);
}
```

**Getting the following compilation problem:**

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'base::fun3' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'boost::shared_ptr<T> &'
```

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: `fun3` expects a pointer to `double`, you're trying to compile it passing it a pointer to `int` and obviously the compiler doesn't like it. What's weird about that?

Comment: I want to pass the different datatype in fun1 but depending upon the case condition it should call the different functions accordingly.

Comment: The same work if I do not pass shared_ptr and use the default datatype like int or double.

Comment: You know the type at compile time, why not overload one function?

Comment: You don't need a switch. Use function overloading

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates. You have a type error in a branch of code that is not taken, and hope to get away with it. `if(false) { int a = "foo"; }`. Nope, won't work. Redesign your logic.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot do that. With second phase of template code compilation for any type the `switch` block has to be fully compiled by compiler. It will will fail to compile. You are mixing `templates` with runtime behavior of program. You better write a different function.

Note that `switch` is runtime, not compile time. When you call it as `fun1(0)` the compiler still has to compile it fully for `int`. It won't evaluate runtime `switch` statement and eliminate `fun3`, which takes `shared_ptr<double>`.